# Access on Views in Oracle

Tags: oracle, view, oracle11g, sql-grant

i need to grant access to my views to users. But i dont want them to see the underlying script to create the view. Is it possible in oracle?

SELECT access does not help

Comment: Why does `SELECT` access not help?

Comment: when i give select access they are able to see the script as well.

Comment: How are they seeing the underlying script?  Different tools (or scripts) query different data dictionary tables.  If you have `SELECT` access on a view or `EXECUTE` access on a procedure, you can view the source from the data dictionary.  Most tools, however, won't show you the source code.

Comment: we use TOAD, when the user selects the script tab, they are able to see the underlying script.

Answer (score 2):

If you really need to shield the workings of your views from users then you can write wrappers for them.

```
SQL> conn a/a
Connected.
SQL> select * from t23
  2  /

      COL1 C
---------- -
        42 Y
        99 N

SQL> create or replace view private_v23 as
  2     select col1 from t23
  3     where col2 = 'Y'
  4  /

View created.

SQL> create or replace view public_v23 as
  2      select * from private_v23
  3  /

View created.

SQL> grant select on public_v23 to b
  2  /

Grant succeeded.

SQL>
```

If we now go over to user B, they can run the view but they cannot see how it gets the data:

```
SQL> conn b/b
Connected.
SQL> select * from a.public_v23
  2  /

      COL1
----------
        42

SQL> select owner, view_name, text 
  2  from all_views
  3  where owner = 'A'
  4  /

OWNER                          VIEW_NAME
------------------------------ ------------------------------
TEXT
-------------------------------------------------------------
A                              PUBLIC_V23
select "COL1" from private_v23


SQL>
```

---

You should have good reasons for doing this sort of obfuscation.  You are making life harder for your users, because they won't be able to understand why they get the data they get, or to make reasonable inferences about performance, joining, etc.  Users who have access to TOAD might need that sort of information.

The other thing is that users may still be able to drill into the underlying structure of the view; for instance, if they can run SQL trace and `tkprof`.  It isn't as easy to hide view sources as it is to obfuscate PL/SQL code.